# URL rewriting using .htaccess on local Apache server and OVH

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect the following address

```
http://MyDomain/register           ==>  http://MyDomain/register.php
http://MyDomain/register/code/XXX  ==>  http://MyDomain/register.php?code=XXX
```

Here is my `.htaccess` file so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^register/code/(.*)$ register.php?code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^register/?$    register.php  [NC]
```

It works well on my local Apache server.
It fails when I upload my files to OVH.

The server ignore my first rule and redirects the page to:

```
register.php/code/XXX
```

So the `GET` on `$code` doesn't work.

I guess my local apache server (running on win) does not have the same settings as OVH.
I can't find a rule that would both on both environment. All my files are named lowercase so it's not the issue :(

Any idea?

Thanks!

**Edit 06/28:**

The following rule works on both environment :

```
RewriteRule ^registercode/(.*)$ register.php?code=$1 [L]
```

The problem is not in the `/` between `register` and `code`

ANy ideas are welcome :)

Comment: Did you manage to get the solution. I'm looking for an answer so please post it as answer of your question. thanks

Comment: @gentleboy unfortunately I never managed to have this working properly and updated my URL structure. I ended up using `^registercode/(.*)$` instead of `^register/code/(.*)$`

Comment: I'll pay an expert in Php to look at it as I think this is an ovh issue. I'll let you know if I manage to get it work

Comment: thanks! any update would be great :)